# Unable to click anchor link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, anchor, masonry

I am working on my new website and have a masonry/Pinterest style effect blog board. When you hover over a post it brings up a button which should link through to the blog/single page. Which it will do if you right click and open in a new window but doesn't if you just left click.

i am guessing it is something to do with the javascript I am using to power the masonry style.

The test site is live here: http://zonocreative.co.uk/lee/blog.html

If anyone could help it would be great.

Regards

For reference, here is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title>Lee Bollu - Creative Designer Leigh-on-Sea, Essex</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/columns.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/flexy-menu.css">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

<!--Header-->

    <div class="nav-wrapper">

        <div class="nav-inner">

            <a href="index.html"><img class="logo" src="images/lee-bollu-logo.svg" alt="Lee Bollu Logo"></a>

            <a href="http://www.facebook.com/lee.bollu"><img class="social" src="images/facebook.svg" alt="facebook"></a>
            <a href="http://www.twitter.com/lbollu"><img class="social" src="images/twitter.svg" alt="twitter"></a>

            <ul class="flexy-menu">
                <li><a href="index.html">Work</a></li>
                <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
            </ul>

        </div>
    </div>

<!--Header-->

<!--Recent Blog Posts-->

    <div class="container">
        <div class="container-fluid social-wrapper">
      <div id="social-container"></div>

      <div id="hidden-items">

        <!-- start of an item-->
        <div class="item panel clearfix social-entry">
          <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="content-image">
              <img height="300" src="images/workitem.jpg">

                <div class="social-blog">
                    <span>
                        <a href="single.html">VIEW POST</a>
                    </span>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="doing-intro">
                <h4>Post One</h4>
                <p>Mus molorpor sam, nustintende eum quo blant vellore, quibus maximodi offic tet, ad que et excepudae sed</p>
                <h5><a href="#">Design</a>, <a href="#">Web</a> &#160;&#160;|&#160;&#160; 2nd July 2014</h5>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end of an item-->

        <!-- start of an item-->
        <div class="item panel clearfix social-entry">
          <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="content-image">
              <img height="700" src="images/workitem.jpg">

                <div class="social-blog">
                    <span>
                        <a href="single.html">VIEW POST</a>
                    </span>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="doing-intro">
                <h4>Post One</h4>
                <p>Mus molorpor sam, nustintende eum quo blant vellore, quibus maximodi offic tet, ad que et excepudae sed</p>
                <h5><a href="#">Design</a>, <a href="#">Web</a> &#160;&#160;|&#160;&#160; 2nd July 2014</h5>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end of an item-->

        <!-- start of an item-->
        <div class="item panel clearfix social-entry">
          <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="content-image">
              <img height="200" src="images/workitem.jpg">

                <div class="social-blog">
                    <span>
                        <a href="single.html">VIEW POST</a>
                    </span>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="doing-intro">
                <h4>Post One</h4>
                <p> Mus molorpor sam, nustintende eum quo blant vellore, quibus maximodi offic tet, ad que et excepudae sed Mus molorpor sam, nustintende eum quo blant vellore, quibus maximodi offic tet, ad que et excepudae sed</p>
                <h5><a href="#">Design</a>, <a href="#">Web</a> &#160;&#160;|&#160;&#160; 2nd July 2014</h5>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end of an item-->

        <!-- start of an item-->
        <div class="item panel clearfix social-entry">
          <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="content-image">
              <img height="200" src="images/workitem.jpg">

                <div class="social-blog">
                    <span>
                        <a href="single.html">VIEW POST</a>
                    </span>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="doing-intro">
                <h4>Post One</h4>
                <p>Mus molorpor sam, nustintende eum quo blant vellore, quibus maximodi offic tet, ad que et excepudae sed</p>
                <h5><a href="#">Design</a>, <a href="#">Web</a> &#160;&#160;|&#160;&#160; 2nd July 2014</h5>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end of an item-->

        <!-- start of an item-->
        <div class="item panel clearfix social-entry">
          <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="content-image">
              <img height="180" src="images/workitem.jpg">

                <div class="social-blog">
                    <span>
                        <a href="single.html">VIEW POST</a>
                    </span>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="doing-intro">
                <h4>Post One</h4>
                <p>Mus molorpor sam, nustintende eum quo blant vellore, quibus maximodi offic tet, ad que et excepudae sed Mus molorpor sam, nustintende eum quo blant vellore, quibus maximodi offic tet, ad que et excepudae sed</p>
                <h5><a href="#">Design</a>, <a href="#">Web</a> &#160;&#160;|&#160;&#160; 2nd July 2014</h5>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end of an item-->

      </div>
    </div>
    </div>

<!--Contact Info-->
    <div class="lightgrey-wrapper">
        <div class="container">

            <div class="contact-wrapper">
                <div class="contact-option">
                    <img class="contact-image" src="images/phone.svg" alt="Lee Bollu Creative Designer Contact">
                    <h4>Phone</h4>
                    <p>07769 338 649</p>
                </div>
                <div class="contact-option">
                    <img class="contact-image" src="images/computer.svg" alt="Lee Bollu Creative Designer Computer">
                    <h4>Email</h4>
                    <p>hello@leebollu.co.uk</p>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
<!--Contact Info-->

<!--base-->
    <div class="base-wrapper">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="section group">

                <div class="col span_12_of_12">
                    <p>&copy; 2014 Lee Bollu</p>

                    <a href=""><img class="base-social" src="images/foot-in.svg" alt=""></a>
                    <a href=""><img class="base-social" src="images/foot-drib.svg" alt=""></a>
                    <a href=""><img class="base-social" src="images/foot-fb.svg" alt=""></a>
                    <a href=""><img class="base-social" src="images/foot-twit.svg" alt=""></a>

                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<!--base-->


        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/flexy-menu.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $(".panel a").click(function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var style = $(this).attr("class");
                    var menustyle = $(".flexy-menu").attr("class");
                    if(menustyle.indexOf("light") > -1){
                        $(".flexy-menu").removeAttr("class").addClass("flexy-menu light").addClass(style);
                    }
                    else{
                        $(".flexy-menu").removeAttr("class").addClass("flexy-menu").addClass(style);
                    }
                });
            });

            $(document).ready(function(){  
                $(".flexy-menu").flexymenu({
                    speed: 400,
                    type: "horizontal",
                    align: "left",
                    indicator: false
                });
            });
        </script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/isotope/2.0.0/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/blog-feed.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Lee

Comment: Please post the relevant code here, not just as a link to a live site. When you fix the problem, the link will no longer be relevant to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove `e.preventDefault();` in `$(".panel a").click();`

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".panel a").click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var style = $(this).attr("class");
                var menustyle = $(".flexy-menu").attr("class");
                if(menustyle.indexOf("light") > -1){
                    $(".flexy-menu").removeAttr("class").addClass("flexy-menu light").addClass(style);
                }
                else{
                    $(".flexy-menu").removeAttr("class").addClass("flexy-menu").addClass(style);
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked a treat :)

Comment: Hi @user2536994! If this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your problem:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".panel a").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var style = $(this).attr("class");
        var menustyle = $(".flexy-menu").attr("class");
        if(menustyle.indexOf("light") > -1){
            $(".flexy-menu").removeAttr("class").addClass("flexy-menu light").addClass(style);
        }
        else{
            $(".flexy-menu").removeAttr("class").addClass("flexy-menu").addClass(style);
        }
    });
});
```

This is capturing ALL links within ".panel a" and preventing the default behavior.